# How does the IConvertible interface work with DataRow?

Tags: c#, .net, datarow, iconvertible

I'm just wondering how the `Convert` class and `IConvertible` interface works with a `DataRow`. If I have this code:

```
string s="25";
int x= Convert.ToInt32(s);
```

The call to `Convert.ToInt32(s)` will run the following:

```
((IConvertible)s).ToInt32()
```

So how does this work with a line of code like this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(myDataRow["intField"]);
```

When neither DataRow nor object implement IConvertible?

Comment: Calling a method will not magically transform into calling another method. The method you called might in turn call another method, but that's something different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DataRow fields are exposed as objects, so the call is made to `Convert.ToInt32(object value)`, which does exactly what you said in your question:

```
return value == null? 0: ((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(null);
```

The runtime attempts to perform a conversion from `object` to `IConvertible`. It doesn't matter that `object` doesn't implement the interface; what matters is that whatever actual, concrete type is in the `DataRow` at runtime has to implement the interface. All of the built-in CLR base types implement `IConvertible`, for example, so it will call `String.ToInt32()` or `Boolean.ToInt32()` or whatever. The interfaces are implemented explicitly, so you can't call those methods directly on your own `string` or `bool`, but you could upcast to `IConvertible` and do it.

```
object s = new System.String('1', 3);
var i = Convert.ToInt32(s);

// s = "111"; i = 111
```

If you try to run that method on an object that doesn't implement IConvertible, you'll get a runtime typecast exception:

```
var o = new object();
var x2 = Convert.ToInt32(o);

// throws System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.IConvertible'."
```